# Global variable is not working when trying to assign from the function

Tags: python, input, global-variables, global, variable-assignment

I am learning Python and I am having issues with gobal variable. I have defined the variables globally and then assigning them from the function using the `global` keyword. But still, when it runs the script, it is failing to assign the variable.

Looked at this solution, [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function), and I don't know why his code is working and the same logic in mine is failing. Can't figure out and stuck in the small issue for hours.

```
def player_input():
    player_1_name = input('Please enter your name Player 1.')
    player_2_name = input('Please enter your name Player 2.')
    player_1_symbol='None'
    player_2_symbol=''
    allowed_symbol=['X','O']
    symbol_accepted = False

def get_symbol():
    global player_1_symbol
    player_1_symbol = input('Please enter your preferred symbol {}. It can be either X or O.   '.format(player_1_name))
    print('value of symbol after assignment: '+ player_1_symbol)

def validate_symbol():
    global symbol_accepted
    print('value of symbol when process started: '+ player_1_symbol)
    if player_1_symbol.upper() in allowed_symbol:
        print('it passed')
        symbol_accepted = True
    else:
        print('it came here, because it did not find the value of player_1_symbol')
        get_symbol()

while symbol_accepted == False:
    validate_symbol()

if player_1_symbol.upper() == 'O':
    player_2_symbol = 'X'
else:
    player_2_symbol = 'O'

print("{}, unfortunately you don't have choice. You have been assigned the symbol {}.".format(player_2_name,player_2_symbol))
```

The result I am trying to achieve is I want to `assign player_1_symbol` to global variable from get_symbol function. And the same goes for `symbol_accepted`. None of the variables are getting assigned. I am printing them but I can't just understand why it is not working. I saw a couple of videos on youtube and some articles.

I saw some other videos/articles on input validations, but once I started this I would like to learn what is wrong with it so I can work with `global` in the future.

Comment: What do you mean they aren't getting assigned? Please provide a [mcve]. Note, this is simply a function definition, it is never called anywhere

Comment: Note, while `player_1_symbol` is global in `get_symbol`, it is local in `player_input` and non-local in `validate_symbol`. In any case, **you shouldn't be relying on global mutable state anyway**

Comment: So when I run the script, variable ```player_1_symbol``` first gets assigned as ```X``` but when it reaches to the point where it runs ```validate_symbol``` function it gets value as ```None```. I am expecting it to keep the value as ```X``` or ```O``` as per user input.

Comment: Side-note: defining the `player_1_symbol` and `player_2_symbol` in `player_input()` function is *really* of no use, since you are defining them again at run-time within `get_symbol()`. The 2nd comment explains it very well why one shouldn't depend on individual *global* variables (too much scope limitations/un-used memory in stack).

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: Sure, I removed global in my local and when I run I am back to square zero. So this is what it is happening.
```Please enter your name Player 1.A
Please enter your name Player 2.B
value of symbol when process started: None
it came here, because it did not find the value of player_1_symbol
Please enter your preffered symbol A. It can be either X or O.   X
**value of symbol after assignment**: X
**value of symbol when process started**: None```

Comment: I un-indented all the function definitions that you had nested inside `player_input()` because I assumed it was a question code formatting issue — but, it might be the cause of the issue if you really have them inside the first function like that…

Answer (score 1):

I created an array with player_symbols (player_1 is at 0 and player_2 is at 1) so the variables can be assigned correctly. I also fixed a bug where validate_symbol was repeating because symbol_accepted had the same error.

```py
def player_input():
    player_1_name = input('Please enter your name Player 1.')
    player_2_name = input('Please enter your name Player 2.')
    player_symbols = ["", ""]
    allowed_symbol = ['X', 'O']
    symbol_accepted = False

    def get_symbol():
        player_symbols[0] = input(
            'Please enter your preferred symbol {}. It can be either X or O.   '.format(player_1_name))
        print('value of symbol after assignment: ' + player_symbols[0])

    def validate_symbol(symbol_accepted):
        print('value of symbol when process started: ' + player_symbols[0])
        if player_symbols[0].upper() in allowed_symbol:
            print('it passed')
            symbol_accepted = True
        else:
            print('it came here, because it did not find the value of player_1_symbol')
            get_symbol()
        return symbol_accepted

    while symbol_accepted == False:
        symbol_accepted = validate_symbol(symbol_accepted)

    if player_symbols[0].upper() == 'O':
        player_symbols[1] = 'X'
    else:
        player_symbols[1] = 'O'

    print("{}, unfortunately you don't have choice. You have been assigned the symbol {}.".format(player_2_name,
                                                                                                  player_symbols[1]))
player_input()
```

Comment: so your solution works, but why only variable does not work instead of the list?

Comment: Having only the variable doesn't work because when you create player_1_symbol inside of a function python recognizes it as a new variable, not a global variable. As other commenters have said it isn't the best practice to use "global x" in your code, so I made a list containing your variables.